# Improving "What should a programmer experienced in high-level OOP language learn when moving to low-level C development?"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

How can the following question be improved to allow it to be reopened and answered?

[What should a programmer experienced in high-level OOP language learn when moving to low-level C development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/298167)

One could argue it is asking for education advice, or is too broad, or is asking for a list of things, or what project to take up next. However, one could also argue that at its core it has an answerable question of at least average quality.

What should be done to improve this question?

Comment: Part of the difficulty with it is that the Title is one question (asking for a condensed version of K&R), the second paragraph is another set of questions (asking for what amounts to a lesson plan for a hypothetical person), and the third paragraph is a what project to take up?  To be possibly salvageable, something within the scope of the site that isn't too broad needs to be identified from the set of the questions that can be realistically answered (and not with a condensed version of the K&R). Ideally, a problem that the OP is encountering rather than a hypothetical that can morph.

Comment: I think the only way it has a chance to work is collab effort, like [this one about web dev](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before) (note: _chance_, there's no guarantee that it will work that way)

Comment: ...just noticed, it's rather a blatant duplicate of [How to think as a C programmer after biased with OOP language?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/285433/31260)

Answer (score 6):

I made a significant edit to this question. The core *problem* is more or less [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/285433/52929) as gnat points out.

And as I said in my comment on the question:

> @KarlBielefeldt there is an [edit] button that anyone, including you can use to edit. It took me about 2 minutes to edit this question significantly and focus it to be (more) in scope here. I believe I still preserved the author's intent, too. Understanding the differences between high level OOP and low level C is the core question (not what to learn). Rather than arguing in comments why not do the same (this is for everyone)? It's frustrating for me to see so many people arguing about the scope of this question rather than *doing something* to edit the question.

Comment: I think some people (myself included) hesitate to edit a question when it is unclear _and_ when editing it introduces significant risk of losing the author's intent. In a case like this, however, the point is rather moot. Unless it is edited it will end up closed, deleted, and relegated to a bad memory.

Comment: @Snowman I've made a lot of very significant edits to questions in my time in SE. When you have someone like the OP here who is actually interested in making their question on topic and I leave a comment explaining why I did very, very few of them are not appreciated.

Comment: @enderland My experience here is that, sadly, a lot of askers are *not* interested in making their question on-topic/answerable (especially the ones asking opinion polls and design-this-for-me questions), and as far as I know there's really no way to find out which OPs are which other than leaving a comment that tries to explain the problem, and see if they respond positively to that.

Comment: @Ixrec this approach is quite popular at TWP (see [Aggressive Edits](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2153/168) at their meta) and my understanding is, as long as asked doesn't actively oppose to edit made, it is considered okay (assuming as usual that edit keeps existing quality answers intact)